# call field by name not index in database table in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have a table in database , the table have a lot of field , when i want to call a fiel of record may call by index like thise :

```
cursor.getString[0];
```

but i want call like bellow :

```
cursore.getString[name];
```

how i can do this.

in php is :

```
$sql="select * from $tablename  order by id desc limit 10";
if ($result=mysql_query($sql,$link))
{
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
{
$titr=$row[titr];
name=$row[name];
}
```

i want this in android:

```
$row[name]
```

Comment: And what have you tried? You're pretty close to the solution in case your ``cursor`` is a ``ResultSet``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
//cursor.getColumnIndex("name") will return the index of column name
```